# Dart toList() vs [...iterable] comparison

Tags: flutter, dart

Given an iterable I have to perform some operation like [map()](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) then return a list.
Two alternatives work, namely using a [toList()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.1/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html) or using the spread operator and square brackets.

**Method with toList()**

```
return iterable.map(myMethod).toList();
```

**Method with spread operator**

```
return [...iterable.map(myMethod)];
```

Which syntax should I prefer, why? Are there performance implications?

Comment: Use whatever is clearest!

Comment: I prefer using `[...iterable]` because IMO it's clearer that it's creating a new `List` object.